# Checkmark's associated with wrong row in TableView when using SearchBar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, accessorytype

I am creating an application where when a User searches for an item in the TableView they can click on it and a checkmark appears next to it. However, say when I select the first item I have searched for and click it then delete my search the checkmark stays on the first row but for a completely different object, I searched for, to begin with (see images below).

[When Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwKAn.png)

[When not Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGBvH.png)

```
var searchingArray = [Symptoms]()
var filteredArray = [Symptoms]()

var selectedSymptoms = [Symptoms]()

var clicked = [String]()

var searchingUnderWay = false

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = searchingSymptomsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraSymptoms", for: indexPath) as? ExtraSymptomCell {

        let searchingArrays: Symptoms!

        if searchingUnderWay {

            searchingArrays = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]


        } else {

            searchingArrays = self.searchingArray[indexPath.row]

        }

        cell.updateUI(symptomNames: searchingArrays)

        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }


}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedRow: Symptoms!

    let symptomName: String!

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

    if searchingUnderWay {

        selectedRow = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        symptomName = filteredArray[indexPath.row].name as String

        if clicked.contains(symptomName) {

            cell.accessoryType = .none

            let indexNumber = clicked.index(of: symptomName)
            clicked.remove(at: indexNumber!)

            if let element = selectedSymptoms.index(where: { $0.name == selectedRow.name }) {

                selectedSymptoms.remove(at: element)
            }

        } else {

            clicked.append(symptomName)

            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

            searchingSymptomsTableView.reloadData()

            selectedSymptoms.append(selectedRow)

        }



    } else {

        selectedRow = searchingArray[indexPath.row]
        symptomName = searchingArray[indexPath.row].name as String

        if clicked.contains(symptomName) {

            cell.accessoryType = .none

            let indexNumber = clicked.index(of: symptomName)
            clicked.remove(at: indexNumber!)

            if let element = selectedSymptoms.index(where: { $0.name == selectedRow.name }) {

                selectedSymptoms.remove(at: element)
            }

        } else {

            clicked.append(symptomName)

            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

            searchingSymptomsTableView.reloadData()

            selectedSymptoms.append(selectedRow)

        }


        print(clicked)
        print(selectedSymptoms)



    }

}
```

I wish for the item I searched using the searchbar to still be checked when you delete the search.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TableViewController logic. It seems really strange, but it works correct)
You need to override prepareForReuse() method in your ExtraSymptomCell. And clear all the values your cell contains including accessoryType

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    accessoryType = .none
}
```

In your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = searchingSymptomsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraSymptoms", for: indexPath) as? ExtraSymptomCell {

        let symptomName: String!

        let searchingArrays: Symptoms!

        if searchingUnderWay {

            searchingArrays = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]
            symptomName = filteredArray[indexPath.row].name as String

        } else {

            searchingArrays = self.searchingArray[indexPath.row]
            symptomName = filteredArray[indexPath.row] as String
        }

        cell.updateUI(symptomNames: searchingArrays)

        if clicked.contains(symptomName)  {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is working perfectly, so simple compared to other 'attempted' answers out there!

Comment: @Basil cell.updateUI - is a method of ExtraSymptomCell. You don't have it in UITableViewCell. Just skip

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableViewCell` are reused, the checkmark will appear in a cell when you reload Table Data.

In cellForRowAt set the accessoryType to .none, to remove a previously checked cell checkmark:

```
let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
cell.accessoryType = .none
```

This will remove the check from the previous search.